# Accessing external file JSON data from beyond scope of $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, scope

I have to convert a 2-character country code to a longer name, and am thinking it would make sense to store these in an external JSON file rather than hard-coding within the script itself.  I'm able to read the JSON to an array, but seem to have a scoping issue:

```
    var countries = {};
    $.getJSON("countrycodes.json", function(data) {
        for (let i in data) 
                countries[data[i].code] = data[i].longname;
        console.log(countries["MX"])     // logs "Mexico"
    });
    console.log(countries["MX"])         // Undefined
```

My countrycodes.json looks like this:

```
[
    {"code" : "US", "longname" : "United States"},
    {"code" : "CA", "longname" : "Canada"},
    {"code" : "MX", "longname" : "Mexico"},
    {"code" : "RU", "longname" : "Russia"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant access the data outside of the ajax call becasue its asynchronous it will be visible in some time and hence the outer console.log will always print undefined.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess the only solution is make the call synchronous?  I understand this normally wouldn't be recommended, but I'm not too concerned about the delay in loading a tiny 5 KB text file from the local website:

```
    var countries = {};
    $.ajax({ url: "countrycodes.json", async: false, dataType: 'json', 
         success: function(data) {
             for (let i in data) 
                     countries[data[i].code] = data[i].longname;
         }
    });
    console.log(countries["MX"])        // Logs "Mexico"
```